# Calling a WebMethod via AJAX without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, webmethod

I have the following WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string InnerGetURL(string accessCode)
        {
            string newURL;
            newURL = (string)HttpContext.Current.Cache[accessCode + "l"];
            return newURL;
        }
```

Is it possible to call that WebMethod from JavaScript, via AJAX BUT without using jQuery. I've managed to create the needed functionality using jQuery but now it's the time to switch to pure JavaScript and AJAX.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Call-WebMethod-from-Javascript-in-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: Content isn't available anymore. Would of been more helpful if you added the code snippet(s) in here though.